# wordpress member

Tags: members

I still have in mind that we must use a plugin to manage members in worpdress.

This thought is years old because people use to say wp's members section was not really secure or well made/devloped or whatever else.

**Is this thought still relevant ?**

I realize after installing "WP Simple Membership Plugin" (free), that I need just a page of connexion, profile and a "list of events published" pages.

1. Members will write Events (CPT) with a front-end form I've made
2. I will publish their drafts after checking them.
3. Members will have a page where all their publications will be listed in order to modify them if needed (approx. same front-end form to create a draft).
4. Perhaps a form page to modify their profile mail or name, entities ...
5. There's no payment
6. There's no private content or private publications except the page where their own publications will be listed

Thanks for your thoughts and replys.

Nico.

Answer (score 0):

That thought is kind of subjective.

Dealing with wordpress membership mostly just needs messing with its built-in role and capabilities, unless you really have a complex membership setup which you shouldn't have use wordpress to begin with.

But for a basic membership, a typical set-up involves the following.

1. Create a custom roles and assign specific capabilities for your members, make sure you have different roles and capabilities for different membership type, this is crucial for the security of your membership set-up. You can find more info [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/)

Additionally, you can mess and test with different roles and capibilities using a plugin like this [one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)

2. Create a registration form which integrate the payment system you want to use (if you need a paid membership). only 3 things needed on this process.

- check the users table and make sure the email provided is unique and does not exists in users table before succesful submission.
- determining successful payment for paid membeship
- create the user after form submission and assign them to the their specific role.

I remember setting up a basic membership a decade ago where I only use gravity form for registration and payment capture process, all I did was execute something on different gf event hooks

and thats it. you have a membership set-up.

For backend access of your members like creating custom post type, this relies on the capabilities you assign to them.

For front-end access, you can use [user_can](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/user_can/) or [WP_User::has_cap](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_User/has_cap/) to restrict specific pages intended for specific members